# MethodImpl(NoOptimization) on this method, what does it do? And is it really nessecary?

Tags: c#, optimization, cil

Well, I wanted to hash a password, and i had a look at how ASP.net Identity does in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto` Class, and i came along this function (which is used to compare the 2 password Hashes):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
private static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (((a == null) || (b == null)) || (a.Length != b.Length))
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        flag &= a[i] == b[i];
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This is a direct copy from the reflector output...

Now my question is, **what is the NoOptimization attribute good for**, and why should it be there(what would happen if i remove it)? To me, it looks like a default Equals() implementation until the `for`-loop.

I tried to have a look at the IL but it is all nonsense to me :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If a "smart" compiler turned that function into something that returns `false` as soon as a mismatch was found, it could make code using this function vulnerable to a "timing attack"---an attacker could conceivably figure out where the first mismatch in a string was based on how long the function took to return.

This isn't just science fiction, actually, even though it may seem like it is.  Even with the Internet in the way, you can take a whole bunch of samples and use some statistics to figure out what's going on if you have a guess that the implementation short-circuits.

Comment: Thanks for this, i often use premature loop termination for performance reasons myself, but i never thought about it being attack-able! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer. Was just wondering why the loop was not optimized to stop when the value was false. Great answer!

Comment: @tmyklebu Quite correct, and now a horrendous prominent exploit works as you describe on the branch prediction machinery that's fundamental to modern CPUs. See https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf, *i.e.,* around page 10 or so (PDF page 11).

Answer (score 2):

There may also be cases where the **JIT compiler** either

1. Has an error in its optimization process or
2. Code optimization may produce an error because it optimizes code in some unexpected way.

I have encountered situations where an optimized method behaved differently from a non optimized.  (I believe this was case A from above).  Declaring just that one method as

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
```

solved the problem.